# How to structure folder to best fit Git?

Tags: git

I am introducing git and am somewhat confused about the best way of constructing a good folder/file structure that fits git. I am using both git and bup backup. I do want to be able to "breakout" a git structure from private to public.

My question is how to structure git in relation to to other "git:s". Is it best to have one "git" or to have a root "git" with many subfolder that have their own "git" ?.

The aim is to minimize the administration and complexity.
The main structure as start point is somewhat like this:

- Root (hard disk)

-- projects (git repository, main).

---> project-1 (git repository)

---> project-2 (git repository)

---> project-3 (git repository)

-- shared  (git repository)

-- unsorted
- exluded from git.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, but in general it's a bad idea to nest git repositories.

Comment: @Daniel H Sorry about the confusion, probably due to that I am new to git. Sound that best would be that I skip the top-level git and avoid to nest git?

Comment: @DanielH It is not a bad idea ... using git submodules he should be fine. Clearly it depends on his scenario if the structure makes sense, but this we can't really know.

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName Git submodules can work and are sometimes a reasonable solution, but they add a lot of complexity. I would say usually the benefits aren't worth the cost, especially if somebody is new to Git anyway and hasn't shown that they have a good reason for submodules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no single best way to structure a project but generally every project has its own repository (a single `.git/` folder in the root of the project).

So instead of having a main repository with submodules for all of your projects you could have multiple repositories and no 'main repository'.

This is all subjective however, as different structures apply to different projects.

Here's an example of a project structure that's often used:

```
.
└───example_project
    ├───.git
    ├───[configuration files]
    └───src
        └───[project files]
```